# Stubbing 3rd party API calls in Rails integration tests

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, capybara, integration-testing, webmock

I have a `TwitterAPI` class defined, which interacts with Twitter's API.  The methods in the module make two separate API calls.  So I have two WebMock `stub_request`s defined in before blocks in my unit tests for the `TwitterAPI` class.

I am writing capybara/rspec-based integration tests now.  Some of the test scenarios involve pages that use Twitter API data, e.g.:

```
feature 'View Twitter feed,' do

  let(:twitter_feed_page)      { TwitterFeedPage.new }
  let(:user)                   { FactoryGirl.create :user }

  scenario "Twitter feed is displayed" do
    login(user)
    twitter_feed_page.load
    expect(twitter_feed_page).to have_text("Test tweet")
    # etc.
  end
end
```

I want these integration tests to use the same stubbed data as my unit tests. So the stub_requests will be shared among multiple tests.  Should I just move the stub_requests I've defined to my `rails_helper.rb` and have some sort of flag that allows specific tests to use the stubs?  Or should I just copy/paste the stub_requests to the integration test itself?  Having multiple copies of the stub requests is not the DRY way to do this, but it seems easier to read/understand how the stubbing works.

Comment: Did you get this sorted out?

Answer (score 2):

When reusing stubs, I do like to put them in a shared file. I also like to wrap them as methods. So, I might have a file called something like `stubbing_helper.rb` in my `spec` folder that looks something like:

```
# spec/stubbing_helper.rb
def stub_successful_twitter_feed_load
  # a stub goes here
end 

def stub_failed_twitter_feed_load
  # another stub goes here
end
```

Naturally, remember to `require` this file in `rails_helper.rb`:

```
# spec/rails_helper.rb
...
require 'rspec/rails'
# Add additional requires below this line. Rails is not loaded until this point!
require 'stubbing_helper'
...
```

Then call the appropriate stub method as appropriate:

```
feature 'View Twitter feed,' do

  let(:twitter_feed_page)      { TwitterFeedPage.new }
  let(:user)                   { FactoryGirl.create :user }

  scenario "Twitter feed is displayed" do
    stub_successful_twitter_feed_load
    login(user)
    twitter_feed_page.load
    expect(twitter_feed_page).to have_text("Test tweet")
    # etc.
  end
end
```